How to setup strongswan VPN server on Linux Debian so that it could be used with Windows 10 built-in client?
I see that www.strongswan.org could be somehow used as a VPN server on Linux (Linux Wonderland 4.19.0-25-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.289-2 (2023-08-08) x86_64) which could be accessed by Windows 10 build-in VPN client, but I can't see straightforward manual how to setup it.
Can you please help with a guide/guidance here?
